# Spring Cloud OAuth2: Adding user authorities

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

We manage to setup a web application with Spring Cloud OAuth2, which implements single sign-on from different identity providers like Facebook and Google, by following [this](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/tree/master/github) sample source code.

Planning to have our own authentication/authorization server, we provided our own `UserDetails`, and `GrantedAuthority`, where we associated user's Facebook and Google. We also have our own set of user authorities other than `ROLE_USER`.

We have our business methods secured based on user's role (we used `@RolesAllowed`). When a user sign-in using their Facebook and Google accounts, only `ROLE_USER` is added as their authorithy. I would like to know how to add our own user authorities from the associated user's `GrantedAuthority` upon signing into external identity providers, though I found that this can be possibly done using `AuthoritiesExtractor`, but can't find concrete example on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to modify/set authorities using `AuthoritiesExtractor`, which is set to `UserInfoTokenServices`.

Comment: great. This was very useful